# Transforming negative numbers to Date or POSIXct object

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have been meaning to transform some 4 to 2 digits negative numbers (indicating BCE dates) into Date objects. Before that I wanted to unite the Year, Month and Day column in order to form a single column.
I will appreciate it if you guys have any idea on how I could possibly do that using lubridate.

```
> NOAA_data %>% slice(10:30)
# A tibble: 21 x 39
   `Search Paramet~  Year    Mo    Dy    Hr    Mn   Sec   Tsu   Vol `Location Name` Latitude
   <chr>            <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>              <dbl>
 1 NA               -1050    NA    NA    NA    NA     0    NA    NA JORDAN:  SW:  ~     29.6
 2 NA                -759    NA    NA    NA    NA     0    NA    NA ISRAEL:  JERUS~     33  
 3 NA                -590    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     7    NA LEBANON:  SUR ~     33.3
 4 NA                -550    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA GREECE:  MOUNT~     37  
 5 NA                -525    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     8    NA LEBANON:  SUR ~     33.6
 6 NA                -480     9    29    NA    NA    NA  3469    NA GREECE:  SARON~     37.9
 7 NA                -479    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     9    NA GREECE:  MACED~     39.7
 8 NA                -432    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA GREECE:  ROMAN~     37  
 9 NA                -426     6    NA    NA    NA    NA    10    NA GREECE:  EUBOEA     38.9
10 NA                -400    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA IRAN:  REY,EIV~     35.5
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach might be the experimental `gregorian` package:

```
#remotes::install_github("edgararuiz/gregorian")
library(gregorian); library(dplyr)
data %>%
  mutate(across(Mo:Dy, replace_na, 1)) %>%
  mutate(Date = as_gregorian(paste0(Year,"-",Mo,"-",Dy)))
#   Search.Paramet  Year Mo Dy Hr Mn Sec  Tsu Vol    Location.Name Latitude                                                                        Date
#1              NA -1050  1  1 NA NA   0   NA  NA  JORDAN:  SW:  ~     29.6    1051, 1, 1, TRUE, Thursday, 4, -1050-01-01, Thursday January 1, 1051 BCE
#2              NA  -759  1  1 NA NA   0   NA  NA  ISRAEL:  JERUS~     33.0         760, 1, 1, TRUE, Tuesday, 2, -759-01-01, Tuesday January 1, 760 BCE
#3              NA  -590  1  1 NA NA  NA    7  NA  LEBANON:  SUR ~     33.3           591, 1, 1, TRUE, Monday, 1, -590-01-01, Monday January 1, 591 BCE
#4              NA  -550  1  1 NA NA  NA   NA  NA  GREECE:  MOUNT~     37.0         551, 1, 1, TRUE, Tuesday, 2, -550-01-01, Tuesday January 1, 551 BCE
#5              NA  -525  1  1 NA NA  NA    8  NA  LEBANON:  SUR ~     33.6           526, 1, 1, TRUE, Friday, 5, -525-01-01, Friday January 1, 526 BCE
#6              NA  -480  9 29 NA NA  NA 3469  NA  GREECE:  SARON~     37.9 481, 9, 29, TRUE, Wednesday, 3, -480-09-29, Wednesday September 29, 481 BCE
#7              NA  -479  1  1 NA NA  NA    9  NA  GREECE:  MACED~     39.7       480, 1, 1, TRUE, Saturday, 6, -479-01-01, Saturday January 1, 480 BCE
#8              NA  -432  1  1 NA NA  NA   NA  NA GREECE:  ROMAN~      37.0           433, 1, 1, TRUE, Monday, 1, -432-01-01, Monday January 1, 433 BCE
#9              NA  -426  6  1 NA NA  NA   10  NA  GREECE:  EUBOEA     38.9          427, 6, 1, TRUE, Saturday, 6, -426-06-01, Saturday June 1, 427 BCE
#10             NA  -400  1  1 NA NA  NA   NA  NA  IRAN:  REY,EIV~     35.5       401, 1, 1, TRUE, Saturday, 6, -400-01-01, Saturday January 1, 401 BCE
```

Comment: Thank you very much dear Mr. Campbell for your solution. I asked this question almost 3 months ago while I was working on an assignment. There were few rows of negative years and I had been wondering how I could make use of them.

Comment: I found your question through the Close Vote review queue. I fear it may be closed soon, but hopefully this package will be useful to you.

Comment: It's quite helpful thank you for your solution. Back in the days I didn't even know I had to share a reproducible data as I'm always telling others to do so now. Thank you again and if I had any question with regard to this I will discuss it with you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the current best practice is to set the date in CE and then subtract the years to get to BCE. Arithmetic might be sketchy because there is no year zero, but this example seems to work as desired:

```
lubridate::ymd("0000-09-29") - lubridate::years(480)
```

For further detail, you can go through [Tayflo's exhaustive explanation](https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/2#issuecomment-753272151) on lubridate's github issue about BCE dates, which has just been reopened this a couple of days ago.

Edit:
For your particular data, you can just paste the values into the lubridate::ymd_hms() function and it will parse it into a single column

```
NOAA_data %>% mutate(date = ymd_hms(paste0(c('0000','-', Mo,'-', Dy,
                                           '_', Hr,':', Mn, ':', Sec))) - 
                                     lubridate::years(Year))
```

You'll also have to add a few ifelse()'s for your NAs, setting each one to a reasonable default value (eg, 01 for day, 00 for minutes, etc). I won't add that to my example code because it would be rather harder to read.

Comment: Thank you very much dear @phenymass for the link.

Comment: You're welcome. I also added to my reply the code that you'll need for your current data setup.